# Getting lastIndex with Validation

Tags: c#, winforms

im doing some experiment on how can i get specific index of string in richTextBox Control .

scenario:
I need to find lastIndex of `#>` but doesnt match with `##>`

reason (2) `##` will block `#`

heres what i started for now:

```
string text = richTextBox1.Text;
int lastIndexOffragment = text.LastIndexOf('#>');
```

Q: How can i find the real last Index of `#>` with validation thats its not `##>`

**--- updated**

*Note: if possible no loop (e.g foreach or forloop)*

sample string in rtb:

```
#> 000010 IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
#> 000020 PROGRAM-ID. K1.
##> 000030
#> 000040 ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
#> 000050 INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
##> 000060 FILE-CONTROL.
#> 000070     SELECT  OPTIONAL LOGIN-TABLE1
##> 000080     ASSIGN TO "LL22"
##> 000090     ORGANIZATION IS INDEXED
verified #> 000100     RECORD KEY IS LPASSWD
done ##> 000110     ACCESSING MODE IS COMPLETED .
```

result should be the index of `#>` after the word `verified`

Comment: can u show the sample string here?

Comment: @Shell I think what's meant is that `"aaa #> ##>".LastIndexOf("#>")` is `8` but OP needs `4`.

Comment: @Shell applied . thats the string that i used to test .

Comment: @artm yes your right

Comment: @artm exactly but, its difficult to find last index of character in string with regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is very ugly method but, i think this will be very easy and not complecated.

```
str = "your string";

int iLastIndex = str.Replace("##>", "^^>").LastIndexOf("#>");
```

you can use any character instead of `^`.

Answer (score 0):

Try regex for exact match:

```
int lastIndexOffragment = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(richTextBox1.Text, @"\#>\W").Index;
```

**Update:**

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex rx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"\#>\W");

System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(richTextBox1.Text);
int lastIndex = matches[matches.Count - 1].Index;
```

Comment: does it match with ##> ?